# the connection between unform convergence and a sequence of positive real converging to zero

Tags: real-analysis

A sequence of function $(f_n)$ is said to converge unformly to $f$ if for every $\epsilon >0$ there exist $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for every $n\geq n_0$ and for every $x \in X$ $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$.

From that definition, is it true that if $f_n \stackrel{u}{\rightarrow} f$ then we can find a sequence $(a_n)$ of positive real converging to 0 and $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for every $n\geq n_0$ and for every $x \in X$ $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<a_n$.

I have some idea on how to create $a_n$ that satisfied for every $n\geq n_0$ and for every $x \in X$ $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<a_n$, that is $a_n=||f_n-f||$ where $||f_n-f||=sup |f_n(x)-f(x)|$. It is obvious that $a_n$ converge to 0, but i cant guarantee that $a_n$ contains positive real for every n.

Is there any other way to create that kind of $(a_n)$?

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. For $f_n$ to converge uniformly to $f$ is equivalent to $\sup_x ||f_n-f||\to 0$. So if you define $a_n=\sup_x ||f_n-f||$, then those $a_n$ satisfy the condition you wanted. I don't know what you mean by "$a_n$ contains positive real for every $n$". There are infinitely many other sequences $a_n$ which satisfy the condition you wanted, just take for example $\lambda a_n$ with $\lambda > 1$.

Comment: what i mean is it true that if $f_n$ converge uniformly then there exists a sequence $(an)$ of positive real converging to 0 and $n0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for every n≥n0 and for every $x\in X, |f_n(x)−f(x)|<a_n$.

Comment: the sequence $(a_n)$ which i define can contains 0 as its element, so it cant be guaranted that $(a_n)$ is a sequence of "positive" real

Comment: @JackM what i mean is it true that if $f_n$ converge uniformly then there exists a sequence $(a_n)$ of positive real converging to 0 and $n_0 \in N$ such that for every $n≥n_0$ and for every $x\in X, |f_n(x)−f(x)|<a_n$. the sequence $(a_n)$ which i define can contains 0 as its element, so it cant be guaranted that (an) is a sequence of "positive" real

Comment: Then just define $a_n = \sup_x \|f_n -f\| + \frac{1}{n} $.

Comment: @Ranc brilliant. Thank you so much :)